# Как построчно заменить текст в файле с помощью writeStream.write?

Tags: javascript, node.js, файлы, gulp, потоки-данных

Есть файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
someText

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body class="wrapper">

    <main class="page">

    </main>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

В нем с помощью `nodejs` и `gulp` хочу заменить строки `.*?<script.*` и `.*?<link.*` на подключения стилей и скриптов wordpress. Делаю с помощью fs.writeStream так как он позволяет записывать в файл построчно. Вот код:

```
gulp.task(`wp`, () => {
    let filepathes = []; 
    return src(project.src.html) // открыли файл
        .pipe(rename({ extname: `.php` })) 
        .pipe(dest(project.build.php)) 
        .pipe(transfob((file, enc, next) => {
            fs.readFile(file.path, 'utf8', (err, doc) => {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                filepathes = file.contents.toString().match(/([`"'])\S+?\.(css|js)\1/gi); // нашли пути к скриптам и стилям
                console.log(filepathes);
                let repleceStrings = file.contents.toString().match(/.*?<(link|script).*/gi);
                let fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(file.path, {flags: `a`, encoding: "utf-8"});
                for (let i in repleceStrings) {
                    let result = '';
                    if (filepathes[i].match(/\.js/)) result = doc.replace(repleceStrings[i], `\twp_enque_script(${filepathes[i]});\r\n`); // формируем строки со скриптами
                    else if (filepathes[i].match(/\.css/)) result = doc.replace(repleceStrings[i],`\twp_enque_style(${filepathes[i]});\r\n`); // со стилями
                    fileStream.once("open", (fd) => { fileStream.write(result);}) // пишем строку в файл
                }
                
            });
            next(null, file);
        }))
}
);
```

Проблема в том, что на выходе я получаю такой файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
someText

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body class="wrapper">

    <main class="page">

    </main>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.min.js"></script>

</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
someText

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    wp_enque_style("css/style.min.css");


    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body class="wrapper">

    <main class="page">

    </main>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.min.js"></script>

</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
someText

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body class="wrapper">

    <main class="page">

    </main>
    </div>
</body>
    wp_enque_script("js/script.min.js");


</html>
```

Объясните, почему все его содержимое дублируется трижды? Как все-таки писать в файл построчно?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, с `gulp` не знаком, поэтому могу предложить только чистый нодовский код для адаптации. Один из возможных вариантов, если нужно использование потоков:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');

async function* processLineByLine(path) {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    // Do something with the line.
    yield `${line}\n`;
  }
}

pipeline(
  processLineByLine('test.txt'),
  fs.createWriteStream('test2.txt'),
  () => { console.log('Done.'); },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Inline plugins](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/using-plugins/#inline-plugins)
>
> Inline plugins are one-off Transform Streams you define inside your
> gulpfile by writing the desired behavior.

```
const path = require('path');
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const through2 = require('through2');

const project = {
  src: {
    html: `${__dirname}/*.html`,
  },
  build: {
    php: path.join(__dirname, 'php'),
  }
};

src(project.src.html)
  .pipe(rename({ extname: `.php` }))
  .pipe(through2.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
    if (file.isBuffer()) {
      let raw = file.contents.toString(enc);
      raw = raw.replace(/(?<=\<link.+?href=["'])(.+)(?=['"].*?>)/g, "wp_enque_style('$1')");
      raw = raw.replace(/(?<=\<script.+?src=["'])(.+)(?=['"].*?>)/g, "wp_enque_script('$1')");
      file.contents = Buffer.from(raw);
    }
    cb(null, file);
  }))
  .pipe(dest(project.build.php));
```

Результат:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wp_enque_style('css/style.min.css')">

    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body class="wrapper">

    <main class="page">

    </main>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp_enque_script('js/script.min.js')"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: through2.obj у меня почему-то не захотел запускаться. Задавал про него вопрос тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1327327/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-gulp-through2

Comment: Возможно, я не до конца разобрался с модулем through2, простите. Объяснить такую работу с регулярками могу: Мне нужно было заменить <link.* и <script.*, поэтому было принято решение сначала получить пути к стилям и скриптам, а потом формировать из них новую строку.

Comment: я и не про through2, вообще не про него. чтобы обосновать свой упрёк я составил за 10 минут небольшой [код-ревью](https://pastebin.com/wWBUBrS2) на небольшой кусок кода из вопроса.